# Where's that three weeks for any deadline page? It had a jQuery slider on it

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The Many Memes of Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta)

I remember there was a joke page relating to how Jeff Atwood said any task takes three weeks to complete.

Someone made a webpage that asks you about your task and then answers back with three weeks.

Comment: http://www.cznp.com/6to8weeks/index.php

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're referring to [six to eight weeks](http://www.sixtoeightweeks.com/). Dot com.

Related: [The Many Memes of Meta: 6 to 8 Weeks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19514#19514).